# why Object.prototype.toString.call([]) returns `[object Array]` while [].toString() returns empty string

Tags: javascript

If I do it in this way:
`Object.prototype.toString.call([])` the code returns `[object Array]`, whereas if I do it in this way `[].toString()` it returns an empty string. Why?

Comment: Because with the first you use the more generic `Object.toString()`, while the latter uses the specific `Array.toString()`.

Comment: Because they're different functions? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/toString

Comment: These two functions don't do the same thing at all.
The first one tries to tell you what kind of variable `[]` is, meaning that `Object.prototype.toString.call([])` or `Object.prototype.toString.call(["a","b","c"])` will always return `[Object Array]` (it does not depend on the array's content).
On the contrary, the second function tries to give you a string representation of your array, meaning that `[].toString()` will return "" (an empty string) whereas `["a","b","c"].toString()` will return `"a,b,c"`.

Comment: Thanks everybody, the answer is clear now